# exit from click handler

Tags: javascript

How do you exit from an event?

```
$('.more').click(function() {
   if (condition1) {
      if (condition2) {
         // abort, exit completely out of click handler
      ...
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `return` there:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
   if (condition1) {
      if (condition2) {
         // abort, exit completely out of click handler
         return;
```

**See:**

**[Interrupting a function Safely](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/valid4.shtml)**

Answer (score 1):

`return;`

That will take you out of the function that is associated with the on click handler;

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also use break here.

```
$('.more').click(function() {
   if (condition1) {
      if (condition2) {
         // abort, exit completely out of click handler
         break;
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem seemed to be solved with neither `break` nor `return` so I ended up solving it by giving the script tag an ID and then removing the full script from the DOM after the click event finished:

```html
<script id="clickEventScript">
document.querySelector('.where-the-user-clicks').addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // do the things
    document.getElementById('clickEventScript').remove();
  }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

It's a bit of a messy hack but it does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I no longer use anonymous functions because my understanding of JavaScript jumped to a new plateau when I started naming them. And besides, naming your functions provides a kind of inline documentation:

```
$('.more').click(myFunction)

function myFunction() {
   if (condition1) {
      if (condition2) {
         return
      }
   }
}
```